# Sharepoint 2010 reporting from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know the easiest and fastest way to retrieve data from SQL Server 2008 R2 via Sharepoint 2010.

I am new to sharepoint but have been able to create an external content type using Sharepoint designer which connects to the database in SQL Server but I have not been able to use the business web chart to relay the data gotten from the database.

I want to relay information from a customer service database into sharepoint and want it to be consistent.

Is this the best way to go about it or is there a better way?

Many thanks for your usual cooperation and response.

Cheers,

Tunde

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is SQL Server Reporting Services, which will need to be installed in Sharepoint integrated mode. It does not have to be 2008 R2, it can be 2008, and the good news is that if you run reporting services on the same server as your SQL databases, you're already licenced for it.

Take a look at http://www.bidn.com/ for more answers, or ask questions using the #SQLHelp tag on twitter for SSRS, or #SPHelp for sharepoint

Comment: Many thanks Mark for your response. Yes it is installed in Sharepoint integrated mode but the database is not a report services database; can it work?

Comment: Many thanks Mark for your response. Yes it is installed in Sharepoint integrated mode but the database is not a report services database; can it work? I have also created an external content type and data source but I dont know how to pull data from it. Cheers